# How to solve "AWT-Queue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError exception on JasperReports?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have created a runnable jar for my project and when I try to print the report I am getting exception, but from netbeans it is executing fine

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.<init>(JRBaseFiller.java:121)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:77)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:87)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:57)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createFiller(JRFiller.java:142)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:52)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:417)
at UI.NewFrame.jMenuItem3ActionPerformed(NewFrame.java:1269)
at UI.NewFrame.access$3300(NewFrame.java:37)
at UI.NewFrame$32.actionPerformed(NewFrame.java:920)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
```

Here is the library I used for the project

- JasperReport 4.1.3
- Itext
- iReport
- Common-Digister
- Common-Logging
- Common-Beanutils
- Common-Collections
- MySQL JDBC Driver
- JCalendar

And here is my Button Print

```
    File namaFile = new File("src/Laporan/report.jasper");
    try {
        JasperReport jasper = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(namaFile.getPath());
        JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasper, null, kon.getkoneksi());
        JasperViewer.viewReport(jp,false);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Later I found out that I had to add the font manually, but it still didn't work for me.

Comment: Can you share the code on what you have in this method. `at UI.NewFrame.jMenuItem3ActionPerformed()`

Comment: @Beniton sure http://imgur.com/IMR4G6V

Comment: I think it fail to initialize the filters. I am not getting visibility on how or what the report is based. May be you need to check the report file.

Comment: @Beniton `I think it fail to initialize the filters` - Which filters?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jasper Reports + WebSphere 7, ExceptionInInitializerError exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306339/jasper-reports-websphere-7-exceptionininitializererror-exception)

Comment: @AlexK Can you check the exception? Something like JRFiller possible I may not be able to tell without knowing what report is about :-)

Comment: @user3083282 You can follow the link provided by Alex K. Check the comments in questions for answers. **_Solved this by using the "javaflow" version of jasper reports, and including Apache commons-javaflow.jar. Never did figure out why it works fine in QA_**

Comment: @user3083282 BTW, it is a good style/idea to use [imports](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html) in Java code

Comment: @AlexK thanks for the link but i already add the javaflow before and the result are still the same. maybe the caused is like said. it's on the report. i'm newbie to Jasperreport anyway

Comment: Did you try to debug (with atached JR source code)?

Comment: Do you have a maven project?

Comment: I would bet this is a library problem (conflict versions ecc)

Comment: @AlexK i tried to debug it before but the exception still the same. and about the maven, no i don't have one

Comment: @PetterFriberg i use 'jasper 3.0.1 
Common-Collection 3.2.1
Common-Beanutils 1.8.2
Common-Logging 1.2
Common-Digister 1.7
MySQL jdbc 5.1.23
iTextpdf 5.3.0 
jCalendar 1.3.2
Groovy 2.1.7
Jasper 6.2.2'